# problem: Linear equation question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

the question is:

$$(y^2+xy^3)\mathrm dx + (5y^2-xy+y^3\sin(y))\mathrm dy = 0$$

can any body tell me how to solve this linear equation?? when I tried to solve this the expression of integrating factor becomes too much difficult, may be i calculated it wrong... 
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Linear equation? The unknown function must be $x=x(y)$, then.

Comment: @Sadia: Looks to me to be an exact equation.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd divide through by $y^2$ to make your life easier. Then the partial differential equation for the integrating factor becomes

$$xu+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(1+xy)=-\frac{1}{y}u+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(t-\frac{x}{y}+y\sin y)\;.$$

That happens to have a solution with $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$, so you can determine an integrating factor $u(y)$ from it.

Comment: Partial differential equation? OP has a linear DE (in $x$), there's a formula for the integrating factor, no need to solve a PDE, is there?

Comment: @Gerry: This is not what I'd call a linear DE (in $x$); it contains $x\mathrm dx$. If you mean the formula given e.g. here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#Use_in_solving_first_order_ordinary_differential_equations, I don't think it applies in this case; at least I don't see how to bring this equation into that form (after swapping $x$ and $y$).

Comment: sorry, must have posted while my brain was in neutral.

Answer (score 0):

$(y^2+xy^3)~dx+(5y^2-xy+y^3\sin y)~dy=0$

$(xy^3+y^2)~dx=(xy-5y^2-y^3\sin y)~dy$

$\left(x+\dfrac{1}{y}\right)\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{x}{y^2}-\dfrac{5}{y}-\sin y$

Let $u=x+\dfrac{1}{y}$ ,

Then $x=u-\dfrac{1}{y}$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{du}{dy}+\dfrac{1}{y^2}$

$\therefore u\left(\dfrac{du}{dy}+\dfrac{1}{y^2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{y^2}\left(u-\dfrac{1}{y}\right)-\dfrac{5}{y}-\sin y$

$u\dfrac{du}{dy}+\dfrac{u}{y^2}=\dfrac{u}{y^2}-\dfrac{1}{y^3}-\dfrac{5}{y}-\sin y$

$u\dfrac{du}{dy}=-\dfrac{1}{y^3}-\dfrac{5}{y}-\sin y$

$u~du=\left(-\dfrac{1}{y^3}-\dfrac{5}{y}-\sin y\right)~dy$

$\int u~du=\int\left(-\dfrac{1}{y^3}-\dfrac{5}{y}-\sin y\right)~dy$

$\dfrac{u^2}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2y^2}-5\ln y+\cos y+c$

$\left(x+\dfrac{1}{y}\right)^2=\dfrac{1}{y^2}-10\ln y+2\cos y+C$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{cases} M(x,y)=y^2+xy^3 \\\\
N(x,y)=5y^2-xy+y^3\sin y\\\\
\end{cases}

\begin{cases} \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=2y+3xy^2 \\\\
\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-y\\\\
\end{cases}

so non-exact

$p(y)=\frac{3y(1+xy)}{-y^{2}(1+xy)}$

$p(y)=\frac{-3}{y}$

$μ(y)=e^{\int\frac{-3}{y}dy}=e^{\ln(y^{-3})}=y^{-3}$  , integrating factor

$(y^{-1}+x)~dx+(5y^{-1}-xy^{-2}+\sin y)~dy=0$

$\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-y^{-2}$

so exact

$f(x,y)=\int(y^{-1}+x)~dx+h(y)=\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x}{y}+h(y)$

$-xy^{-2}+h'(y)=5y^{-1}-xy^{-2}+\sin y$

$h(y)=\int (5y^{-1}+\sin y)~dy=5\ln(y)-\cos y$

$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x}{y}+5\ln(y)-\cos y=c$$